# Order of Second Ionisation Potential of C, N, O and F

Tags: periodic-trends

Here's what I believe:

The electronic configurations of the elements after losing 1 electron are:

N<sup>+</sup> -> 1s<sup>2</sup> 2s<sup>2</sup> 2p<sup>2</sup>

O<sup>+</sup> -> 1s<sup>2</sup> 2s<sup>2</sup> 2p<sup>3</sup>

F<sup>+</sup> -> 1s<sup>2</sup> 2s<sup>2</sup> 2p<sup>4</sup>

So, on losing 1 e<sup>-</sup> more, the value of the second ionisation potential would be in the order:
F<N<O (as F would be obtaining a stable half filled p-orbital which would contribute to greater stability)

But, most books I've referred suggest that the order of ionisation potentials is N<F<O.

Could you explain how N is more stable despite F having half-filled p-orbitals?

Comment: A fluorine nucleus definitely doesnt have the same impact with a nitrogen nucleus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_ionization_energies_of_the_elements#All_Ionization_Energies) ionization energy table somewhat splits the difference. Ignoring a difference of less than 1% between O and F as likely within experimental uncertainty, that table gives

N(2856) < O(3388) = F(3374) < Ne(3952).

where all numbers are in kJ/mol. The inclusion of neon in this sequence indicates that the second ionization of fluorine is indeed lowered by the favorable half-filled shell configuration. But this effect is only enough to balance one additional nuclear charge in the same period comparing fluorine with oxygen. With fluorine versus nitrogen, the larger difference in nuclear charge (two instead of one) wins out.